# Mongoid: How to inverse a 1-N relationship, and store foreign key on parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm creating a **Profile** that describes a person. Included in this description is information about what **Industry** they work in (i.e. "Computers & IT"). So the relation is defined such that:

`"A Profile has an Industry, but an Industry does not belong to a Profile."`

Looking through [this Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many), I set up my models with the following:

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :industry
end

class Industry
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name,      type: String, default: ''
end
```

Now I know ordinarily you would add a `belongs_to :profile` to the **Industry** class. However, according to the documentation, it adds the foreign key to the child (Industry), not the parent (Profile):

```
# The parent profile document.
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9") }

# The child industry document.
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f1"),
  "profile_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9")
}
```

This is problematic because I don't want an industry to link to profiles, I want profiles to link to industries. **How do I get it to look like this?**:

```
# The parent profile document.
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9")
  "industry_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f1")
}

# The child industry document.
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f1"),
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but shouldn't the `Industry` `has_many :profiles` and the `Profile` `belongs_to :industry`?

Comment: Yea, reversing the `has_one` and `belongs_to` worked. I was thrown off because from an English standpoint, it doesn't make sense to say *"a Profile belongs to an Industry"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the choices of names for relations in Mongoid confusing, but it mirrors ActiveRecord so there you go.  You want:

```
class Industry 
    has_many :profiles 
end

class Profile 
    belongs_to :industry
end
```

The class with `belongs_to` has the FK field.  `has_one` and `has_many` create the associations to find the FK in the other class.

Comment: Heh, yea, realized this after I posted... I really need to get myself a rubber duck to talk to.